# How to release / dispose Windows.Data.PdfDocument

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-10, windows-8.1

The code below will throw an `UnauthorizedAccessException` on Windows 10 1709. On previous versions of Windows 10 (or 8.1), no exception will be thrown. If the line with `LoadFromFileAsync` is commented out, no exception will be thrown.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var source = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\example.pdf");

   var tempFile = await source.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder, "my.pdf", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

   var pdf = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(tempFile);

   await tempFile.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
}
```

As `PdfDocument` doesn't provide methods to free/release the resources which are obviously claimed, this seems to be a bug within the framework. The only workaround I could think of is to pass the data via `LoadFromStreamAsync` to prevent the file from being locked.

So how can a `PdfDocument` be properly released on Windows 10 1709?

[image]

Additional screenshot before the deletion is attempted:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to marshall the resource ? System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pdf)

Comment: @Florian: Thanks, same issue if I add this call.

Comment: Did you try without using the "async workaround" ?
The issue you have seems not to be related to the pdf itself but more about "rights", are you running the app as administrator mode ?

Comment: Yes, the exception message actually reads more like a "Permission denied". But if I comment out the delete part and re-run the program just to delete the file, it works. So it's definitely a resource/handle leak of some sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally went with the workaround to prevent the `PdfDocument` from locking the file:

```
using (var stream = await tempFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
   var pdf = await PdfDocument.LoadFromStreamAsync(stream);
   // do something with the document
}

await tempFile.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
```